# Conditional transforming an expression when encountering default value in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Say I have an expression `x + x^2 + x^3`, and I want to substitute `x` with `y` when the power of `x` is less than its maximal power, below is my code in Mathematica:

```
x + x^2 + x^3 /. x^n_. /; n < 3 -> y^n
```

But the result is `y + y^2 + y^3` instead of `y + y^2 + x^3`. I don't know where is my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Replace`

```
Replace[x + x^2 + x^3, x^n_. /; n < 3 -> y^n, {1}]
```

The levelspec `{1}` holds the replacement to level 1 where the pattern is `Power[x, n]` (unless `n` is omitted).  If replacement is at level 2, the `x` symbols *inside* the `Power` expressions are replaced, with the `n_.` default coming into play.  `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) affects all levels, but `Replace` with levelspec `{1}` does the job.

Without with the `n_.` default an additional rule is required.

```
Replace[x + x^2 + x^3, {x^n_ /; n < 3 -> y^n, x -> y}, {1}]
```

Inverting the main rule allows use of `ReplaceAll`

```
x + x^2 + x^3 /. {x^n_ /; n >= 3 -> x^n, x -> y}
```

An alternative method would be to use `Piecewise`

```
Piecewise[{{y + y^2 + x^3, n < 3}}, x + x^2 + x^3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it. The default pattern represents a replacement x->y, and it affects all levels, that does make sense. So I'd better treat x->y as an additional replacement instead of using the default pattern.